# Proper way to extend multiple classes

Tags: java

So I am making a java program that reads in a bunch of information from a JSON. By the end of it I will have like 80+ methods. I want know how to go about making a single class that can call all 80+ methods, without having to put all the methods in a single place. The ideal solution for me would be

```
public class Item extends ItemStats, ItemPrice, ItemEffects, ItemImage, ItemTree {
...
}
```

I know that this is not possible, so I was wondering the proper way to go about this problem?

Comment: You don't extend a class to be able to call methods of objects of that class. you call them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems likely you really want to use composition instead.

```
public class Item {
   private ItemStats stats;
   private ItemPrice price;
   // etc..

   public ItemStats getStats() { return stats; }
   // etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support multiple-inheritance. You could make all of those interfaces, implement them all in an abstract class and then extend that.

```
interface IItem implements ItemStats, ItemPrice, ItemEffects, 
    ItemImage, ItemTree {
}

abstract class Item implements IItem {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement multiple interfaces or do something like this:

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
public class C extends B {}
...
```